# Schema ignored when applying migrations during runtime for the first time

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Expected/desired behavior: "Members" table is created in "mySchema"

Actual behavior: "Members" table is created in "public" (the default schema)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Test
{
    class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        readonly string connectionString;

        readonly string schema;

        readonly bool isParameterless;

        public MyContext()
        {
            connectionString = @"Server = 127.0.0.1; Port = 5432; Database = empty; User Id = postgres; Password = 123;";

            isParameterless = true;
        }

        public MyContext(string connectionString, string schema)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;

            this.schema = schema;
        }

        public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            if (!isParameterless)
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        }
    }

    class Member
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    class Programs
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new MyContext(@"Server = 127.0.0.1; Port = 5432; Database = test; User Id = postgres; Password = 123;", schema: "mySchema");

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

            Console.WriteLine(context.Model.GetDefaultSchema()); // "mySchema"

            Console.WriteLine(context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Member)).GetSchema()); // "mySchema"

            context.Database.Migrate();

            Console.WriteLine(context.Model.GetDefaultSchema()); // "mySchema"

            Console.WriteLine(context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Member)).GetSchema()); // "mySchema"

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@"CREATE TABLE public.""Members""()"); // Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P07: relation "Members" already exists'

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@"CREATE TABLE ""mySchema"".""Members""()"); // Npgsql.PostgresException: '3F000: schema "mySchema" does not exist'
        }
    }
}
```

Migrations were generated for this code using the following command:

`dotnet ef migrations add init -v`

**Further technical detail**

EF Core version: 3.1.0

Database provider: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL (3.1.0)

Target framework: NET Core 3.0

[VS Project.zip](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/files/3997727/VS.Project.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted a full program so it's not possible to be sure.

However, my guess is that you've created a context via the parameterless constructor before doing so with the other constructor. The EF Core model building, which includes running `OnModelCreating`, runs only once when you first use the context; it isn't redone for every single context you instantiate. As a result, you can't have multiple contexts with different default schemas.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is actually the full code (you can copy/paste it to reproduce the same result). I'm aware of model caching and know how to get around it, but first I'm trying to get HasDefaultSchema() to work.

Comment: I'm missing your actual migration files. But if I replace `context.Database.Migrate()` by `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`, I can see the Members table being created in the `mySchema` schema.

Comment: I created the migration files for this code using this command: `dotnet ef migrations add init`

Comment: `context.Model.GetDefaultSchema()` does return `mySchema`, so it's more accurate to say the default schema is ignored by `Migrate()`.

Comment: It would really help if you posted the migrations file, as well as the *full* steps to generate it. Trying to run `dotnet ef migrations add init` with your code throws `The string argument 'schema' cannot be empty.`, because the parameterless constructor is used by the dotnet tool (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#using-a-constructor-with-no-parameters), and you cannot pass an empty string to HasDefaultSchema().

Comment: Temporarily changing the parameterless construct to initialize schema to `mySchema` and then generating the migration works well, with `mySchema` in the generated migration as the table schema. Executing the program creates the table in the schema as expected.

Comment: My advice is to start from scratch and advance step by step. If you're still hitting an issue, please post the full code *including* the generated migration, as well as the steps you took to generate it.

Comment: Here's the full project: https://easyupload.io/v6kogs (including a .bat that generates the migrations)

Comment: I know that I can set the schema in the parameterless constructor, I want to be able to set a custom schema without having to recreate the migration files.

Comment: btw, I don't get any errors from the dotnet ef tool, even when `schema` is null. Ideally, I'd use a flag (set by the constructor) in `OnModelCreating` and `OnConfiguring` for code that's not shared by user and dotnet ef invocation, but I'm trying to keep the code as simple as possible here.

Comment: More information has been posted in https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/19350.